# How to separate application logic from network layer in Android using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I am new in Android and Retrofit and I am facing one problem.

I want to have my lets say "ServerCommunication" class (singelton) where all Retrofit magic is done and it will have public methods where REST calls are done.

I want to use this "ServerCommunication" instance in my activities to call Rest service, but thats it. Application logic should be done in activity. So this way some activity Login calls method Login(POJORequest) in "ServerCommunication) where actual REST call via Retrofit framework is done and some POJOResponse is returned. So Activity doesn't care about REST communication while ServerCommunication doesn't care about what logic that should be applied to response from REST service since.

With retrofit 2 I do not understand how I can block Activity to wait for response from retrofit and how it can be returned. Well, I might think I can use some callback methods in activity so those methods can be called from ServerCommunication" in OnPostExecute() to apply some logic based on data from response. It's just I think it should be simpler approach.

Well, to clarify all this mess above imagine simple case: You have data in you main activity, you pass this data to your communication class where REST call is done and response is received. This response must be validated in order to continue. And you want this validation to be done in main activity and NOT in communication class.

What is pattern to do that in Android with Retrofit2 ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I normally do:

- Create your Interface (where you have all your REST methods - GET & POST etc)
- Create a class that does the actual calls with corresponding methods (refer to the interface REST methods). I would call it something like ServiceAPIImplementor. This is where you actually create your Retrofit adapter.
- In your activity, create an instance of your implementor class and call the methods and pass the expected arguments.
- After calling the methods, you should probably show a progress dialog to let the user know that something is going on.
- When the **onResponse** or **onFailure** method is called, use an Event pattern (EventBus library?) to notify the activity that the network operation has been completed. Once the activity has received the notification, it should then dismiss the progress dialog and update the UI accordingly - with the newly received data or completed operation (expected outcome).

I hope this helps you get closer to what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well EventBus did the trick, but I still feel it is more like workaround. I still have to include onEventMainThread() to activity where I receive response from  ServiceAPIImplementor (or whatever we acll it) and UI actually is not blocked though we hide it behind some  progress dialog or just simply disable controls. I would like to avoid adding extra Event pattern framework when all I want to do is to have method SomeResponse callRestService(SomeRequest req) in ServiceAPIImplementor

Comment: and simply have instance of it in activity and do something like  SomeResponse resp=serv.callRestService(req); Retrofit 2 has possibility to configure connection and other timeouts so blocking UI is not the issue. So I guess the best solution would be if I can choose when I want do REST calls from UI thread and when from background.

Comment: However if it is not possible I would stick to EventBus solution, but I have one question. Is there any benefits using EventsBus over solution when I just simply implement callback method in activity and call it from  onResponse or onFailure methods in  ServiceAPIImplementor ?

Comment: If it did the trick, would you mind giving even a single upvote? That is if it helped at least. Thanks

Comment: EventBus has been praised by many developers for reasons listed on its Github page; really decouples your project code;

Comment: of course. Your answer I think I will use to decouple Network layer from Application I will give you upvote, of course, it's just I don't have enough reputation score to do that yet.

Comment: Eventbus can be confusing as the project grows because you basically have everybody yelling at everybody else. It becomes hard to track who's actually communicating with whom. Another option would be to use RxJava and have your implementer return an Observable of your objects. The learning curve on RxJava can be steep at first but this would be a good easy place to start (no mapping or other modifier methods, etc just emitting values).

Comment: i am trying to implement the same thing , can u provide some sample code for it

Answer (score 0):

Service interface (IPhotoService):

```
@GET("/photos/kudos")
Call<String> fetchKudos(@Header("Authorization") String authorization,
                        @Query("offset") int offset, @Query("mt") boolean mt);
```

Service impl (PhotoService):

```
private GoApiProvider<IPhotoService> mGoProvider = new GoApiProvider<>();

public Promiser<List<Photo>, HttpError> fetchKudos() {
    return new Promiser<>((resolve, reject) ->
            mGoProvider.getService(IPhotoService.class).fetchKudos(mSession.getToken(),
                    mOffsetKudos, true).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        PhotoParser JSON = new PhotoParser();
                        try {
                            mOffsetKudos = mOffsetKudos + 20;
                            resolve.run(JSON.photosFromJson(response.body()));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("fetchKudos", e.toString());
                        }
                    } else {
                        reject.run(new HttpError(response.code(), response.message()));
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                    reject.run(new HttpError(YPErrorType.Undefined.getType(), t.getMessage()));
                }
            })
    );
}
```

Activity or Fragment :

```
private void loadPhoto() {
    new PhotoService().fetchKudos()
            .success(this::resultSucceeded)
            .error(this::resultError);
}

private void resultSucceeded(List<Photo> photos) {
    mPhotoAdapter.setItems(photos);
}

private void resultError(HttpError httpError) {
    httpErrorToast(httpError);
}
```

If you want to use Promizer: [Click here](https://github.com/NodensN/android-promiser)